# How do I fix this spec file: it keeps giving me sed errors yet the only sed is long before the error occurs?

Tags: fedora, rpm, packaging

[Here](https://gist.github.com/590683724f48ed9f4f06ad5143a7d759) is my codelite.spec file. It compiles the sources fine, but then it gives this error (and yes I am including a few extra lines to give context):

```
Processing files: codelite-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64
Executing(%doc): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.zYPKNH
+ umask 022
+ cd /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILD
+ cd codelite-10.0
+ DOCDIR=/home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/codelite-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64/usr/share/doc/codelite
+ export DOCDIR
+ /usr/bin/mkdir -p /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/codelite-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64/usr/share/doc/codelite
+ cp -pr AUTHORS /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/codelite-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64/usr/share/doc/codelite
+ cp -pr LICENSE /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/codelite-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64/usr/share/doc/codelite
+ cp -pr COPYING /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/codelite-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64/usr/share/doc/codelite
+ exit 0
Finding  Provides: /bin/sh -c " while read FILE; do echo "${FILE}" | /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps -P; done | /bin/sort -u "
Finding  Requires(interp): 
Finding  Requires(rpmlib): 
Finding  Requires(verify): 
Finding  Requires(pre): 
Finding  Requires(post): 
Finding  Requires(preun): 
Finding  Requires(postun): 
Finding  Requires(pretrans): 
Finding  Requires(posttrans): 
Finding  Requires: /bin/sh -c "  while read FILE; do echo "${FILE}" | /usr/lib/rpm/rpmdeps -R; done | /bin/sort -u  | /usr/bin/sed -e 'libcodeliteu.so; libpluginu.so; libwxscintillau.so; libwxsqlite3u.so;'"
/usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
Provides: application() application(codelite.desktop) codelite = 10.0-1.fc25 codelite(x86-64) = 10.0-1.fc25 libdatabaselayersqlite.so()(64bit) liblibcodelite.so()(64bit) libplugin.so()(64bit) libwxshapeframework.so()(64bit) libwxsqlite3.so()(64bit) mimehandler(application/x-codelite-project) mimehandler(application/x-codelite-workspace)
Requires(interp): /bin/sh /bin/sh /bin/sh
Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1 rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
Requires(post): /bin/sh
Requires(postun): /bin/sh
Requires(posttrans): /bin/sh
Processing files: codelite-debuginfo-10.0-1.fc25.x86_64
error: Empty %files file /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILD/codelite-10.0/debugfiles.list


RPM build errors:
    Empty %files file /home/fusion809/rpmbuild/BUILD/codelite-10.0/debugfiles.list
```

there's only one `sed` command in this spec file, on [line 87](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/590683724f48ed9f4f06ad5143a7d759#file-codelite-spec-L87) which is in the `%build` macro but this error occurs later around the time of running `%files`. Any ideas where this sed error comes from? I have tried the following efforts to fix this error:

1. Removing [L118-120](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/590683724f48ed9f4f06ad5143a7d759#file-codelite-spec-L118)
2. Removing [L122](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/590683724f48ed9f4f06ad5143a7d759#file-codelite-spec-L122) and changing [L127](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/590683724f48ed9f4f06ad5143a7d759#file-codelite-spec-L127) from `%files -f %{name}.lang` to `%files`.

Neither attempt has succeeded, or even changed the error message I get. I am building this package locally (with `rpmbuild -ba codelite.spec`) on my 64-bit Fedora 25 system.

Comment: OK, any solutions? Or at least workarounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the `%filter_from_requires` on line 60 that is wrong.

According to [EPEL:Packaging Autoprovides and Requires Filtering](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL:Packaging_Autoprovides_and_Requires_Filtering#Removing_items_from_the_requires_stream_.28post-scan_filtering.29):

> The `%filter_from_requires` macro is used to filter "requires"; it does for requires what the `%filter_from_provides` macro does for provides and is invoked in the same fashion.

Regarding the `%filter_from_provides` macro, it says

> This macro can be fed a sed expression to filter from the stream of auto-found provides.

On line 60, you do not provide a sed expression.

I guess you could use

```
%filter_from_requires /lib\(codelite\|plugin\|wxscintilla\|wxsqlite3\)u\.so/d
```

... or something similar.